# Die Bedeutung(en) der Traumbeine

Tags: meaning

Ich habe das Wort "Traumbeine" im Wörterbuch gesucht, aber ich konnte die Bedeutungen nicht finden. Dies Wort steht in der folgenden Text unseres Deutschbuchs.

*Titel: Kleider machen Leute
... "Der Rock sollte am besten knielang sein. Auch wenn die Frau noch so schöne **Traumbeine** hat, sollten diese weitgehend verdeckt bleiben"...*

Hat dies Wort auch andere Bedeutungen außerhalb diese Text?

Danke für euere Antworten!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mit dem [Affix *Traum-*](https://dwds.de/wb/traum-) drückt man aus, dass etwas so perfekt ist, wie man es nur in einem schönen Traum erleben kann.

*Traumbeine* sind also perfekte Beine.

Andere Beispiele

> [Traumfrau](https://dwds.de/wb/Traumfigur)
>   [Traumurlaub](https://dwds.de/wb/Traumfigur)
>   [Traumjob](https://dwds.de/wb/Traumfigur)
>   [Traumfigur](https://dwds.de/wb/Traumfigur)

*Traumbeine* wird offenbar nicht häufig genug benutzt, um einen Eintrag in einem Wörterbuch zu rechtfertigen.

Comment: Ich wüsste auch nicht, das Wort "Traumbeine" je gehört zu haben. Werbetexter erfinden solche Sachen natürlich gerne (Traumhaus, Traumurlaub, Traumjoghurt...).